# Change value of div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how could I change a position of a div, based on scroll level of my website? I have a landing screen (whole page fullscreen background) only with big centered logo. What I'm asking is, how to do that it'll scale down and catch into a navbar, where it'll be sticked, untill it would be scrolled up again.

I did a video showcase, how I mean it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fecyRsOkz8&feature=youtu.be

I'm so glad for any help, have a nice day, senior coders! :)

Comment: What have you tried till now? Where is the code? If not try using skrollr plugin, play with it and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the 
http://jsfiddle.net/rjv2016/occL21s3/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var aDivPosition = $('.adivclass').height();
alert($(this).scrollTop());
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= aDivPosition) {
    $("#adiv").hide();
    $("#adiv1").position({
      my: bottom,
      of: $window,
          collision: "fit"
    });
}
});
```

The fiddle only has the needed code. You will have to work out the .position method if not, post back your update (with your code).